# git pushing to a branch post merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging

If I push to a branch after merging it with `master`, how will git handle it (Update the latest commits pushed in branch to `master` automatically OR do nothing OR do something else) ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After the merge you still have 2 branches, the one that you merged *from* and the one that you merged *into*, which is usually still your active branch.

The new commit will go to branch that is checked out and that is either master or the other branch.

Note, that we don't *push to a branch*: we *commit* to a branch and push the branch to a remote repository. And we do not update commits, we add new commits to the repository. Commits *never* change.

**Addition** - Sure, you still can push to the "old" branch. And merge it into master again:

```
A - B - - - E - G      [master]
     \     /   /
      C - D - F        [issue_202]
```

But I'd prefer creating a new branch to fix the issues. It's a question of workflow. Assume, the work is ticket-based, then the issue_202 ticket goes to resolved *before* you merge into master. So to my opinion, the additional work is not a fix on the issue_202 but a fix for the master branch and so I would create a new ticket and a new branch to fix the issues:

```
              F        [issue_202_1]
             / \
A - B - - - E - G      [master]
     \     /  
      C - D            [issue_202] [
```

Comment: thanks @Andreas_D , I will give some more details to explain my doubt. I had fixed some issues in branch `issue_202` and pushed the branch to remote. Now the branch is merged with master, but I received further comments to the fixes done in the branch `issue_202` after the merge. My doubt is whether I should checkout `branch_202` and fix the issues OR checkout a new branch like `branch_202_dot_1` from master, fix the issues and push the branch to master ?  
My basic question is after merging can we commit to a branch and push to remote ? if yes, then how will it again be merged with master ?

Comment: @twalberg - yes, you're right. I change my answer in that point. Of course, only the active branch receives the merge commit, the other is of course unaffected.

Comment: the best explanation on the internet till now :)

Answer (score 1):

In Git, a *commit* is a snapshot of your repository plus pointers to one or more parent plus some metadata (like author, and commit message).

A *branch* is a pointer to some commit. That's it.

When you push a branch, you update the remote's pointer to point to the same commit as yours. In addition, your local repo and the remote repo negotiate what snapshots the remote is missing and sends those to the remote. Otherwise, the newly updated remote branch would point at a commit that it knew nothing about.

So, if you push a branch, only that remote branch will change. All the other remote branches will point to the exact same commits as they did before. That said, [git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) `push.default` can make it easy to push more than you expect. I recommend `git config --global push.default nothing`.

You should probably read up on [Git Branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching) some more.